unable to build basic activity project in Android Studio. (I recently downloaded and installed Android Studio)

error 1 : C:\\Users\\heman.gradle\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\e4b508a549ae243ca5a91a89dbd9f745-3fd4b24e-98d8-45f3-80ad-6ed926390f12 -\> C:\\Users\\heman.gradle\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\e4b508a549ae243ca5a91a89dbd9f745
error 2 : A build operation failed.
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\\Users\\heman.gradle\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\e4b508a549ae243ca5a91a89dbd9f745-3fd4b24e-98d8-45f3-80ad-6ed926390f12) to immutable location (C:\\Users\\heman.gradle\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\e4b508a549ae243ca5a91a89dbd9f745)

Could not move temporary workspace (C:\\Users\\heman.gradle\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\e4b508a549ae243ca5a91a89dbd9f745-3fd4b24e-98d8-45f3-80ad-6ed926390f12) to immutable location (C:\\Users\\heman.gradle\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\e4b508a549ae243ca5a91a89dbd9f745)

I completely reset my PC and download Android Studio again.
I downloaded the JDK and set environment variable in JAVA_HOME an also set path to location of JDK.
I checked on command prompt and java version available.
Deleted cache and restarted application.
But the error is still occurring.

C:\\Users\\heman.gradle this path doesn't look correct, I assume this should be C:\\Users\\heman\\.gradle (not sure why the backslashes are escaped here). Have you modified the posted log output or is this the original output? If it is the original output something is wrong with your Windows user account. Please post the path of Windows user profile folder %userprofile%.
